# Rstudio-server won't start after updating to R 3.5.0: Error occured during transmission

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I have recently moved from MRO 3.4.3 to R 3.5.0. I can start and use the new installation of R perfectly from the terminal, but when I stat Rstudio-server, an error panel appears with the message: "Error occured during transmission"

The log at `/var/log/messages` shows this:

`Jun  6 11:28:51 slave1 rsession-victor[116037]: ERROR R SUICIDE: unable to initialize the JIT|||; LOGGED FROM: void<unnamed>::rSuicide(const std::string&) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:1023`

I have tried to remove the files `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` and `/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf` that I had changed to use the previous MRO installation, but it didn't work. Also, I have tried to to remove completely the `.rstudio` folder in my home directory.

Any ideas about how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an incompatability issue on the server-side. I would contact an admin for your server, if there is one.

Comment: Unfortunately it's me the responsible for managing this server :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after installing R 3.5.1 from sources. 
The reason for the error is that libR.so is not build using the
simple installation procedure described in file INSTALL. RStudio 
searches for this and finds an incompatible (old) one. Use this instead:

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib
make
```